# Should all headings have an ID?

Tags: website-design, heading

In a web page in which there are several sections and heading levels, should the headings have an id attribute? Is there a best practice/rule of thumb from a UX perspective?

It looks like it would be improve user experience (allowing them to share deep links to specific sections), but it also feels like an overkill (it may not be a frequently used feature and could increase page weight, although not considerably).

Comment: You mean the section links like on wikipedia?

Have you checked on the weight increase? Does it really matter?

In my opinion if there are clearly visible links to "share this section" next to the section header, your users are likely to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for a rule of a thumb, the only one I could think of would be:

**Empower your Users by offering them bespoke solutions** that can be delivered at a **reasonable balance between cost&profit** from the business standpoint.

This statement may be just too obvious, but if you look closely, you will find that it is split into two parts with the first one being related strictly to UX Design, and the latter to the external context it is embedded in, which is business (for me, together they constitute strategic Product Design).

Therefore, to decide if a feature should be implemented or not, some questions need to be answered:

- Is there a best practice showing the correct way?
- Is this feature something Users need?
- Is there a business reason to do this?

This is not a closed list of questions, though, there may be other ones that could play an important role (depending on the system you work on, relations with your stakeholders, their expectations and business goals etc.).

For this particular case, some answers that can be given would be:

**Is there a best practice showing the correct way?**

No, I think there is not. I can come up with several ideas when giving headers an unique ID in code should be done, but it is not based on best practice, rather on particular Users' needs.

**Is this feature something Users need?**

This is what you need to figure out yourself, I believe. Should this feature **empower them** and make the system more **bespoke**, then the answer would be **Yes, you probably should.** However, mind the business point of view.

**Is there a business reason to do this?**

To answer this question, you need to know:

- what the **cost of the implementation** is (measured in time, money, dependencies created by this decision etc.),
- how it **relates to the profit** (measured in for example Users' number increase, increased monetisation time savings for Users sharing the links etc.),
- how these together relate to the whole **product strategy**.

It may look big, but in fact it is not always so. In your case, I believe the cost of implementation would be very low – it would not take (probably) a lot of time and money to implement it, and probably it would not make the interface too cluttered for Users. Regarding the gains – on one hand, this may be a really rarely used feature (same as linking to specific sections on Wikipedia for me - I use Wikipedia very often, but have used direct linking to a section only one or two times probably). However, **should it be a system where Users' performance linking to particular section have a relatively high importance**, the gain may be really high.

Hence, provided that there is no general rule about the matter of the question, if the gain is low and the cost is low, I would say that the importance of this decision is quite low and the rule of the thumb might be rather to skip it for now and return to it when the business reason for it appears.

This is the only rule of a thumb that comes to my mind.